# Datatable jquery does not show data

Tags: html, json, ajax, bootstrap-4, datatable

I am using Jquery Data table to show my data, which cames from an ajax call and a json file.
I'm using two tables, the first one (#list1) shows data from sql, the second one (#list2) is filled when I click on one of the rows in the first table (a click event). I was strougeling with the reload data, I used clear() and draw() to reload the table, but after using this, the second table  (#list2) stop displaying the info, only if you go and click on it will appear the data. I guess ist the way I'm reloading the tables but no other method has work for me.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(
                function()
                {

                 $('#list1').DataTable(
                  {
      
                   dom: 'lfrtipB', //elementos del DOM y orden 
                   buttons: ['csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']

                   });
                 $('#list2').DataTable(
                    {
                    responsive: true,
                    searching: false,
                                        
                    });
  
                    $("#list1 tr").click(
                            function ()
                            {
                                var cod = ($(this).find("td:first").text());
                                $.ajax({
                                url: 'https://www.urlblabla.php',
                                data: {
                                    action: 'usuario',
                                    idfiltro: cod
                                        },
                                    type :'post',
                                    success: function(sql) 
                                    {   
                                        var t= $('#list2').DataTable().clear().draw();
                                        $.each(JSON.parse(sql), function(idx, opt)
                                        {
                                            t.row.add([ opt.1, opt.2,opt.3,opt.4]).draw(); //this was my mistake I add the draw() method
                                        }); 
                                    }//endsuccess
                                }); //endajax
                            }//end function
                    );//end click
                }
            );//fin document ready
```

I tried to use the reload() function but the browser gives me a function not found error

And here is my html code (quite simple)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link href="libreriasWS/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="libreriasWS/jquery.dataTables.min.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="libreriasWS/datatable_style.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="libreriasWS/buttons.dataTables.min.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libreriasWS/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libreriasWS/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libreriasWS/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>    
        <div id="content" class="container">

                    <div class="datatable-inner table-responsive ps ps--active-x">
                    <h4>Users</h4>
                    <table id="list1" class="table datatable-table hover">
                        <thead class="datatable-header">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>name</th>
                                <th>Line</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                            <?php   
                                $cli = $soapClient->getData("","array_data","");
                                $result_array = json_decode($cli);
                                    
                                for ($i=0; $i < count($result_array); $i++) 
                                { 
                                    print '<tr>';
                                    print '<td>'.$data_array[$i]->{'Id'} .'</td>';
                                    print '<td>'.$data_array[$i]->{'name'} .'</td>';
                                    print '<td>'.$data_array[$i]->{'line'} .'</td>';
                                    print '</tr>';
                                }//finfor
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    
                

                            <div class="datatable-inner table-responsive ps ps--active-x">
                                <h6>Users</h6>
                                <table id="list2" class="table datatable-table hover">
                                    <thead class="datatable-header">
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                                        <th>MAC</th>
                                        <th>Cliente</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                    <br/>



            </div> <!--Fin Tab Content-->
        </div> <!--Fin Tab Content contaniner-->
    </center>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to clear and repopulate the second DataTable when you click on a different row in the first table, you'll need 'destroy: true' in your initialisation. You can add an Ajax call in the DataTable initialisation as well.

It might be better to have the second table initialised in a separate function, then pass the variable from table 1 as a parameter e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#list1 tr").click( function () {
    var cod = ($(this).find("td:first").text());

    SecondTableInitialise(cod);
});
});


function SecondTableInitialise(cod) {
    $("#table2").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "methodURL" + cod,
            "dataSrc": "tableSource"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Column1Data" },
            { "data": "Column2Data" },
            { "data": "Column3Data" }
        ],
        "destroy": true
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,  I tried but that didn't work :(  It only show data if I click on it

Comment: Would be better to pass the value from the table to another function to initialise the second DataTable, then use it in an Ajax source for the table. I've edited my answer with an example.

More info on Ajax sources for DataTables here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: Okei, I found out why it wasn's showing, I had to write after the row.add the function .draw() like this:    t.row.add([ opt.1, opt.2,opt.3,opt.4]).draw(); It's not reloading the info but at least its showing it. (I'm going to edit my question)

Comment: What should I write instead of  method in here ("url": "methodURL" + cod)? I dont have a txt file, I mean I'm not saving the file.

Comment: This will be replaced by the "url: 'https://www.urlblabla.php'," line you had in your question. The "+ cod" is adding the value from the first table as a parameter.

Comment: Okei thanks, I changed it also add the method clear() again, and now its working perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Good to hear, no problem.